# Difference between forkIO/forkOS and forkProcess?

Tags: haskell

I'm not sure what the difference between `forkIO`/`forkOS` and `forkProcess` are in Haskell. To my understanding, `forkIO`/`forkOS` are more like threads (analogous to `pthread_create` in C) whereas `forkProcess` starts a separate process (analogous to `fork`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`forkIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO) creates a lightweight unbound *green thread*. Green threads have very little overhead; the GHC runtime is capable of efficiently multiplexing millions of green threads over a small pool of OS worker threads. A green thread may live on more than one OS thread over its lifetime.

[`forkOS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkOS) creates a *bound thread*: a green thread for which FFI calls are guaranteed to take place on a single fixed OS thread. Bound threads are typically used when interacting with C libraries which use thread-local data and expect all API calls to come from the same thread. From [the paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/conc-ffi/index.htm) specifying GHC's bound threads:

> The idea is that each bound Haskell thread has a dedicated associated
>   OS thread. It is guaranteed that any FFI calls made by a bound Haskell
>   thread are made by its associated OS thread, although pure-Haskell
>   execution can, of course, be carried out by any OS thread. A group of
>   foreign calls can thus be guaranteed to be carried out by the same OS
>   thread if they are all performed in a single bound Haskell thread.
>
> [...]
>
> [F]or each OS thread, there is at most a single bound Haskell thread.

Note that the above quotation does not exclude the possibility that an OS thread associated with a bound thread can act as a worker for unbound Haskell threads. Nor does it guarantee that the bound thread's non-FFI code will execute on any particular thread.

[`forkProcess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.1/docs/System-Posix-Process.html#v:forkProcess) creates a new process, just like `fork` on UNIX.

Comment: So, none of these guarantees to create a new OS thread? For example `forkOS` even if called 1 million times could simply create new green threads associated with the same OS thread?

Comment: @Bakuriu I've updated the answer with a quote from the original paper, which clearer and more precise than what I'd originally written. As far as I'm aware there's no way to directly use an actual OS thread in GHC, but I can't think of any particularly compelling reason to do so anyway.

Comment: Well, it does say "For each OS thread there is at most a single bound Haskell thread" which implies that two `forkOS` calls will have to spawn green threads on different OS threads... I didn't really have a usecase for this but I was simply curious. It makes sense that this is the behaviour, otherwise the GHC runtime would have to share the thread-local storage with different FFI calls...

Comment: @Bakuriu I read the spec as saying that not every call to `forkOS` will necessarily create a new OS thread. The runtime could reuse one of its existing worker threads which doesn't already have a bound thread attached to it. Whether or not it actually does that, I don't know - you'd have to ask a GHC dev

Answer (score 4):

`forkIO` creates a lightweight thread managed by Haskell's runtime system. It is unbound, i.e. it can be ran by any OS thread.

`forkOS` creates a bound thread, meaning it is bound to an actual OS thread. This can be necessary when using C functions for example.

`forkProcess` forks the current process like `fork()` in C.